# How to escape in g command's norm mode of Vim

Tags: vim

I want to add `[](` to the beginning of a line and `)` to the end of a line that starts with `http` in Vim.

To do this I am using the following g command:

```
g/^htt/norm I[](
```

Now, I want to press `Esc` key now inside `g` and put `A)`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To be able to use two `:normal` commands in sequence, you have to wrap them in `:execute`. When you use double quotes, you can then write the Escape as `\<Esc>`, like this:

```
:g/^htt/exe "norm I[](\<Esc>" | norm A)
```

Notes:

- Unless you need mappings to apply, using `:normal!` (with the bang) is preferred, because it's more robust.
- You could have also used `:substitute` here.

Answer (score 19):

You can escape the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>followed by <kbd>esc</kbd>.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> will insert the next non-digit literally.

Note: You may have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> depending on your system. (Nice mnemonic is quote)

See help for more information

```
:h c_Ctrl-V
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do with `:s`:

```
:%s/^htt.*/[](&)/
```

Comment: you beat me to it by 4 seconds.

Comment: I know but actually I have a few more requirements that cannot be done by substitute alone.